# Mostrar imagen en MPDF por ruta guardada en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html5, mpdf

Buen día.
Me gustaría saber como puedo mostrar una imagen en MPDF que su ruta esta en la base de datos, lo he intentado muchas veces, pero MPDF no me ha permitido visualizar la imagen, cuando coloca la ruta yo mismo si me muestra la imagen, este es mi código, Agradezco que me ayuden con esto.

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION["usuario2"] == null){
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
?>

<?php 

    include("../gerente/conexion_bd.php");

    $query="SELECT logo_file FROM empresas WHERE nit=".$_SESSION["empresas_nit"];
    $resultado=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
    $consulta=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);





  function getPlantilla(){

   $plantilla = '<body>
        <header class="clearfix">
          <div id="logo">
            <img src="'.$consulta['logo_file'].'" width="100" height="100">
          </div>
```

Comment: En lugar de generar el PDF, envía la salida al navegador, ¿aparece la imagen? Sí: Habría que ver si MPDF requiere alguna acción adicional como convertir a base 64. No: La ruta es incorrecta.

Comment: Amigo muestra la imagen en el navegador, pero en el PDF no, he probado  con base 64 convertirlo y después descodificarlo y nada.

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo con este Foro: https://www.thaicreate.com/php/forum/124768.html